# How to interpret the correlation of fixed effects table in an lmer output?

Tags: r, correlation, lme4

I'm running linear mixed effect models and I'm not sure about how to interpret the "Correlation of Fixed Effect" table from an lmer output.

Here is a dummy example of a mixed effect models, using the iris R inbuilt dataset. I look here at the influence of the Sepal.Width and Petal.Length on Sepal.Length, using Species identity as the random effect (not sure it makes biological sense but it should still do the job).

I create the model

```
m1 <- lmer(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width + Petal.Length +(1|Species), iris)
```

call the summary of the model

```
summary(m1)
```

We get the "Correlation of Fixed Effect" table at the end of the output, which is the following:

```
Correlation of Fixed Effects:
             (Intr) Spl.Wd
Sepal.Width -0.349       
Petal.Lngth -0.306 -0.354
```

My  interpretation would be that for each unit of increase of Sepal.Width ("Spl.Wd" in the table), there is a -0.354 decrease in Petal.Lngth. This would makes sense. But I can't figure out what "(Intr)" means and therefore do not understand the first column.

Would be great if you can help! :)

Comment: If you need help interpreting statistical models, you should ask for help at [stats.se]. That's not really a programming question that's appropriate for Stack Overflow. But presumably "(Intr)" stands for your intercept term in your model. Interpreting correlations in terms of observed units isn't correct as correlation is scaled between -1 to 1. If you want to interpret parameter, you should be looking at effect sizes, not correlations.

Comment: this could help: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/57240/how-do-i-interpret-the-correlations-of-fixed-effects-in-my-glmer-output

Comment: Thank you for your comment and thanks @demarsylvain for the link, which is quite complete. It's clearer now!